# Visibility of plain jar in tycho-surefire-plugin

Tags: tycho, tycho-surefire-plugin

### The problem

I am faced with the following scenario:

The sources of an Eclipse test plugin (tycho packaging type `eclipse-test-plugin`) depend on a "**plain**" jar (read: non-OSGi jar). I managed to get the tests to compile and run in Eclipse, however when running Maven/Tycho **from the command line**, tycho-surefire-plugin fails to execute the tests because the jar is not visible at test time. This results in a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` while attempting to load a class from the jar.

Looking at `mvn -e -X` output does not reveal anything significant.

My question is, how can I include the jar in the classpath of tycho-surefire-plugin when running Maven/Tycho from the command line?

### Attempts

Here is everything I have tried so far:

1. Use `<extraRequirements>` as per the tycho-surefire-plugin [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#dependencies). This however fails because the jar's packaging type is `jar`, while `<extraRequirements>` expects one of the `eclipse-xxx` [packaging types](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Packaging_Types).

For a good measure I also tried

```
<configuration>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>. . .</groupId>
      <artifactId>. . .</artifactId>
      <version>. . .</version>
      <scope>system</scope>
      <systemPath>path-to-the-jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</configuration>
```

but the packaging type is still considered to be `jar`.

2. Use `<argLine>` as per tycho-surefire-plugin [documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/tycho/sitedocs/tycho-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine):

```
<groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
<artifactId>tycho-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
  <argLine>-cp path-to-the-jar</argLine>
</configuration>
```

however this appears to have no effect as the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` persists.

3. Include the jar in the Eclipse test plugin. The jar is present in the `MANIFEST.MF`

```
Bundle-ClassPath: the.jar
```

in the `build.properties`

```
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               the.jar
```

and in the `.classpath` (although this doesn't matter for tycho-surefire-plugin).

```
<classpathentry exported="true" kind="lib" path="the.jar"/>
```

tycho-surefire-plugin once again reports `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

4. Create a dedicated Eclipse plugin to house the jar. This is for the most part equivalent to 3, where the Eclipse test plugin simply depends on this new dedicated Eclipse plugin. The `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` still rears its head.
5. Transition to Tycho 2.x.x since it supports the `Directory` location type. Unfortunately it is not possible to include the jar in the target definition because its packaging type is `jar`.

Comment: The latest versions of Eclipse and Tycho have [support for loading plain non-osgi jars directly from Maven](https://läubisoft.gmbh/en/articles/using-maven-artifacts-in-pde-rcp-and-tycho-builds/), might be worth checking out if your jar is from maven.